# Calling JSON.parse from a function returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, json

I need to store a JSON in a variable. I have the next function:

```
retrieve(){
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
}
```

And i'm trying to store the return of the function in the variable.

```
this.todos = this.retrieve()
```

But I'm getting:

> model.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'retrieve' of undefined

If i do this instead, it works:

```
this.todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
```

Why is that happening?

**Edit: Full code**

```
export default class Model {

constructor(){
    this.view = null;
    this.todos = this.retrieve();
    if(!this.todos || this.todos.length < 1){
        this.todos = [
            {
                id: 0,
                title: 'default',
                description: 'default',
                completed: false,
            }
        ]
        this.id = 1;
    }
    this.id = this.todos[this.todos.length - 1].id + 1;

    retrieve(){
         return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }

}
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: you need to `return` something from a function if you want it to [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) something

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually I tried returning but the outcome was the same so I was just trying without the return and other ways.

Comment: It depends on where are you executing this `this.todos = this.retrieve()`? My be inside an regular function instead of arrow function.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath retrieve() is a class method. this.todos is in the constructor of the class.

Comment: @Spaceguy ok, so are you executing this `this.todos = this.retrieve()` in constructor?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Exactly

Comment: @Spaceguy please provide your complete code or the class definition, because this should work

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I edited and posted the code for the Class, constructor and the method, there are other methods in the Class but they don't really interfere here.

Comment: `retrieve()` shouldn't be in the constructor, you want it as a method of the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class level methods should be outside the constructor.

```
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]))

class Model {

constructor(){
    this.view = null;
    this.todos = this.retrieve();
    if(!this.todos || this.todos.length < 1){
        this.todos = [
            {
                id: 0,
                title: 'default',
                description: 'default',
                completed: false,
            }
        ]
        this.id = 1;
    }
    this.id = this.todos[this.todos.length - 1].id + 1;

}



    retrieve(){
         return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }
}

console.log(new Model());
```